# Creating a MySQL user with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a user a MySQL user with prepared statements for ex.

```
$QueryToCreateUser = $conn->prepare("CREATE USER  '?'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ? ;");
  $QueryToCreateUser->bind_param('ss',$CreateUser,$CreatePassword);
  $QueryToCreateUser->execute();
```

Though when I do this I get a error message

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean...`

is there a way to use prepared statements and create a MySQL user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in:

```
 $QueryToCreateUser = $conn->prepare("CREATE USER  '?'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ? ;");
 $QueryToCreateUser->bind_param('ss',$CreateUser,$CreatePassword);
```

The 
                    prepare()
method can return false and you should check for that.

Also, consider use of something like $conn->error_list to examine errors that occurred parsing the SQL. (I'll occasionally echo the actual SQL statement strings and paste into phpMyAdmin to test, too, but there's definitely something failing there.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a security issue. [How to create new MySQL database user with MySQLi prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780974/how-to-create-new-mysql-database-user-with-mysqli-prepared-statements)
Your best option is:

```
if (!($QueryToCreateUser = $conn->query("CREATE USER  '$CreateUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $CreatePassword ;"))) {
    echo "User insertion failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
```

Be aware that we are overlooking all string sanitation and security issues.
Do not put this code on the front-end(on the wild), only on a secured back-office(Admin).